# Paths in Python/Sage

Tags: python, math

I've been working on this problem (https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSNB9.jpg) asking me to plot all lattice paths in a nxn grid for the last week, and I have no idea how to proceed.

This is about as far as I've been able to get

```py
def NE_lattice_paths(x,y):

    Vn= vector([0,1])
    Ve= vector([1,0])
    plot(Vn) + plot(Ve, start=Vn)
```

I know I have to use vectors, and I have to use the "def" command to make a function, but how would I make a function that can plot every path and know to take a different one each time? What I wrote doesn't really make sense, but I could use some guidance on how to proceed. Thank you!

Comment: Try not to remove too much context from your question. This runs the risk of invalidating existing answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the paths with a nested for loop (or list comprehension).

So this will give all the paths.

```py
def NE_lattice_paths(x,y):

    paths = []
    for i in range(x):
        path = []
        for j in range(y):
            path.append((i,j))
        paths.append(path)


    return paths

result = NE_lattice_paths(5,3)
print(result)
```

result

```
[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)], [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)], [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)], [(4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2)]]
```

I will leave it as an excersize for the OP to do the animation...